# ubuntu software

Tags: ubuntu

I have been working on water cleaning through AI but the software which runs Anaconda3 types software is ubuntu which is quite unfamiliar for me is is possible to work on the same project but on another operating system rather than using ubuntu.

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for alternative software for Anaconda3? Then please say so and add your requirements. Please read [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manage libraries, dependencies, and environments with [Conda](https://conda.io/).

Conda is an open source package management system and environment management system that runs on Windows, macOS and Linux.

Conda easily creates, saves, loads and switches between environments on your local computer.